# Cron jobs high cpu usage

Tags: cron

[image]

This jobs run all time and consuming 25% cpu power each

Answer (score 1):

In your crontab entry, you can specify how often the cron is running. Maybe try running it less frequently.

```
crontab -e

# you see a file

# run cron only every 15 minutes
*/15 * * * * sh /path/to/magento/cron.sh
```

Additionally, look in the MySQL `cron_schedule` table. There you can see every job that is scheduled, and how long it takes to execute. Perhaps a particular job is taking longer than you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved in the latest version 2.2.6

upgrade to 2.2.6 or above latest stable version

Here is the reference link:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12863